# JQuery datepicker not showing properly with css

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is that the calender doesn't show properly (not using googles css)
Here is my code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>      
     <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">   
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>    
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <script>
         $(function () {
             $("#MainContent_startDate").datepicker();
             $("#MainContent_endDate").datepicker();
         });
     </script>
</asp:Content>


<asp:TextBox ID="startDate" CssClass="InfoData" runat="server" TextMode="Date" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="endDate" CssClass="InfoData" runat="server" TextMode="Date" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

I have tried using IE, FF and Chrome. In IE it says at the bottom: "Only safe content is shown". If I then click "Show all content", then the datepicker shows properly with googles css. But in FF and Chrome I don't get this possibility. But I don't think that it should ask this at all, it should just show the datepicker with the right css, as shown on the jquery example. 
Any idea? I saw a many topics with this issue, but not exactly the same as mine

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Please, replace your asp.net code by browser's html code.

Comment: You are using multiple versions of jquery together?

Comment: @QuickSilver I think it is not an issue, check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EZdNe/

Comment: you're jquery selectors don't match the id's of your inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your TextBox control add **ClientIDMode="Static"** to match the ID selector like

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="endDate" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
```

Then keep this header only and datetimepicker should work

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
             $("#startDate").datepicker();
             $("#endDate").datepicker();
         });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're referring wrong selector(**ID mismatch**)

```
  $(function () {
                 $("#startDate").datepicker();
                 $("#endDate").datepicker();
             });
```

check this [http://jsfiddle.net/EZdNe/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/EZdNe/)

Also why are having 2 different css files?

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />   
 <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

This may lead to **CSS Conflict**.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the respond. The IDs should work, those aren't then right IDs, I just added them here on stackoverflow. The date does show according to the ID, it just doesn't use the css from google.
About using 2 css files. I just forgot to remove the 2nd one, it was from a desparate attemt, when I had no more options

Comment: I have added a screenshot so that you can see the issue. You can see it on top with my first post.

Comment: This seems to be css conflict.  Better check with other stylesheets whether any style is getting override.